# Getting value from data attribute and attaching class depending on that value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Pretty straight forward. Trying to get values from data attributes from some li's, depending on those values I want to assign a class of hidden or active. This seems pretty straight forward, but if I console.log without the boolean it returns the values. When using the boolean it hangs up on the first (or last) and applies the .is-hidden to all elements.

**HTML**

```
<li data-sex="male"></li>
<li data-sex="male"></li>
<li data-sex="female"></li>
<li data-sex="female"></li>
<li data-sex="male"></li>
<li data-sex="male"></li>
<li data-sex="male"></li>
```

**JS / JQuery**

```
$('li').each(function() {
  sex = $(this).data('sex');
  console.log(sex);

  if(sex = "male") {
    $(this).addClass("is-active");
  } else {
    $(this).addClass("is-hidden");
  }
})
```

Comment: Use === for comparing, not =

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `===` instead of `=`,

```
if(sex === "male") {
    $(this).addClass("is-active");
} else {
    $(this).addClass("is-hidden");
}
```

You can addClass directly with selector with using each and if condition.

```
$('li[data-sex=male]').addClass("is-active");
$('li[data-sex=female]').addClass("is-hidden");
```

Comment: *without* using each and if :) - this is definitely the best answer

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `==` or `===` instead of `=`,

```
if(sex == "male")
```

Comment: Thanks, totally flew over my head for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

You are using an assignment operator when you should be using a comparison one.

```
if(sex = "male")
```

should be

```
if(sex == "male")
```

`==` or `===` are required when comparing two values.

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I missed that.